# Enable power options from lock screen on Windows 10 Home edition

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen, power-options

I'm using Windows 10 Home. I don't have the option to sleep / restart / shutdown from the lock screen. There are multiple users on this computer.

I just want this button, can't figure out where to enable it!
[image]

Mine only has the 2 buttons for "Network" and "Ease of Access". Power button is missing.

Comment: Are you a local `Administrator` on this device? I originally asked if you are connected to a domain, which is a stupid question, because I then realized `Windows 10 Home` can't be joined to a domain.

Comment: I'm local administrator yes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Local Security Policy is probably more user friendly if you have access to it. However, we Windows Home edition users do not.

"Shutdown: Allow system to be shut down without having to log on." is the same as `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\shutdownwithoutlogon` in the registry.

Navigate to this key:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`

Look for `shutdownwithoutlogon`, set its value to `1`.

If it does not exist, right click → “New” → “DWORD”, name it `shutdownwithoutlogon`, double click the new DWORD and change its value to `1`.

You don't need a restart; if you lock the computer,
you will immediately see the power button is back.

Answer (score 8):

Check your local security policy:

1. Open "Local Security Policy" as an Administrator
2. Navigate to Security Settings, Local Policies, Security Options
3. Enable "Shutdown: Allow system to be shut down without having to log on."

Note: The policy change takes effect immediately.

Comment: I don't believe I have access to Local Security Policy from Windows ***Home***, I think that is a Pro only feature. Do you know of a different way to access that setting?